# Python: modify nonlocal variable after return from outer function

Tags: python, closures, python-nonlocal

Consider the following example:

```
def g():

    in_g=100

    def f1():
        nonlocal in_g
        in_g = 10

    def f2():
        nonlocal in_g
        print(in_g)

    return (f1,f2)


(f1, f2) = g()

f2() #prints 100
f1()
f2() #prints 10
```

Both the inner functions, `f1` and `f2`, have, in their "closures", access to the variable `in_g`.
However, after `g` returns, where is `in_g` kept in the memory?

I assume that while `g` is executing, `in_g` is a variable on the stack frame corresponding to a call to `g`. Therefore, `g`, `f1` and `f2` all access the same memory location (on the stack) when using the variable `in_g`.

But, as seen in the example, after `g` returns, `f1` and `f2` still access the same memory location when referencing `in_g`. However, now that `g` returned, that memory location cannot be on the stack anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the answer here: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.ro/2015/12/how-lookup-works.html.

So, when accessing `in_g`, `g`, `f1` and `f2` access a `cell variable` which, in turn, holds a reference to the actual object.